# Error Setting-up AppFabric Cache Server 1.1 on Local Computer

Tags: windows, appfabric-cache

I’m trying to setup Windows Server AppFabric Cache on my local computer.  Eventually I get to the point of connecting my C# .NET application to the distributed cache and I get an error.   To confirm that the cache is up and running and configured correctly I execute the 
“Get-CacheClusterHealth” in PowerShell.  When I do this I get the following error:

> Get-CacheClusterHealth :
>   ErrorCode:SubStatus:Failed to connect to hosts
>   in the cluster At line:1 char:23
>   + Get-CacheClusterHealth <<<<  -debug
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-CacheClusterHealth], DataCacheException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException,Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Cachi
>   ng.Commands.GetCacheClusterHealthCommand

I'm installing AppFrabic Cache on a work computer that is attached to a domain. Since I just need a proof-of-concept I'm using XML provider.  In the past I have successfully installed AppFabric Cache in other environments, but having issues installing on my local computer.

Since Appfabric Cache is somewhat of a beast to configure, I thought it would be beneficial  that I provide the steps I went through to reproduce the issue:

[image: AppFabric Install]
[image: AppFabric Caching Service Log On]
[image: CacheConfigShare Share Security]
[image: New-CacheCluster]
[image: Confirm XML]
[image: use-CacheCluster]
[image: Security DistributedCacheService.exe.config]
[image: Register-CacheHost]
[image: Grant-CacheAllowClientAccount]
[image: Start-CacheCluster]
[image: Get-CacheHostConfig]
[image: Get-CacheConfig]
[image]
[image: Get-CacheClusterHealth]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  After I registered the host using "Register-CacheHost" I should have called "Add-CacheHost".

[image]

After I called "Add-CacheHost" I then called "Get-CacheClusterHealth".  I finally got the results I expected.

[image]

The primary purpose was to create a Proof-Of-Concept in C# that would access AppFabric Cache on a local computer.  When I executed the application which was running under my credentials I received the following error:

This is error seems to be a catch-all error. I've seen this error multiple times for different issues.

[image]

Since the application was executing with my credentials I needed to give my account permissions to access the cache.  It did this by using "Grant-CacheAllowedClientAccount"

[image]

Now the cache is working with my application.  I was able to get this to work on a computer that was attached to the domain and also to a computer that was in a workgroup.

Comment: Had a similar issue, in our case simply `Grant-CacheAllowedClientAccount` was needed to give the domain account permissions.